# CSS "position: fixed" respects parent's margin property. Why?

Tags: html, css

My understanding is that once an element is provided `position: fixed` property, it is removed from the normal document rendering workflow. But in the below example, the fixed element respects the `margin-left : 300px` property of its parent.

```html
<div style="height: 100vh; background-color: lightblue; margin-left: 300px;">
  <div style="position: fixed; background-color: tomato; width: 100px; height: 100px;">
    
  </div>
</div>
```

And once I provide `top: 0px;` and `left: 0px` property, it stays at the top left as expected. Can anyone explain why the fixed element respects the `margin-left` of parent when `top` and `left` properties are not provided?

```html
<div style="height: 100vh; background-color: lightblue; margin-left: 300px;">
  <div style="position: fixed; background-color: tomato; width: 100px; height: 100px; top: 0px; left: 0px;">
    
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: In your example, it does not. Also, it's best to turn this into a snippet yourself as you are already providing the code. And to make it easily testable, add a larger wrapper in your page as well that gives some scroll space. In the minimal scroll space of your example, the fixed element remains fixed.

Comment: @somethinghere I have improved my question. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: The answer can be found in the CSS specification: when `top`/`left`/`bottom`/`right` are undefined then they're `auto`, which is not the same as `0`:. When a positioned element has `auto` in those properties then their initial value comes from their parent element, hence the implicit `left: 308px;` (due to `<body>`'s 8px padding on my machine), see https://www.w3.org/TR/css-position-3/#abspos-insets

Comment: Thanks @Dai. That was really helpful. You are a hero!

Comment: From the [doc](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-position-3/#staticpos-rect): When both inset properties in a given axis are auto, they are resolved into a static position by aligning the box into its static-position rectangle. 

In my words: When inset properties (top/bottom/left/right) are not set, the element is treated just like a `position : static` element and placed inside it's containing element. Additionally, note that the element will remain fixed in that position during scroll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behaviour you're observing is defined [by the CSS specification's section on positioning](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-position-3/):

The short answer is that it is positioned (0,0) relative to its closest block-level ancestor element (in this case, its parent `<div`) because you didn't set any of the *inset properties* for either axis of the inner `<div>` element.

---

The long answer requires following the spec:

[The *inset properties*](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-position-3/#inset-properties) refer to `left:` and `right:` (for the horizontal axis), and `top:` and `bottom:` (for the vertical axis).

In your case, because all *inset properties* in both axies are undefined, they default to `auto`, and when both properties in an axis are `auto` then the spec says this:

> If both inset properties in a given axis are `auto`, then, depending on the box’s `self-alignment` property in the relevant axis:

(In your case, the `self-alignment` is `self-start`, for lengthy reasons I won't go into)

> ...for `self-start` alignment or its equivalent: Set its `start-edge` inset property to the *static position*, and its `end-edge` inset property to zero.

[The values for an element's *static position*](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-position-3/#staticpos-rect) are determined by recalculating the box's shape/layout/etc if `position: static` were used instead (emphasis theirs):

> When both inset properties in a given axis are `auto`, they are resolved into a static position by aligning the box into its **static-position rectangle**, an *alignment container* derived from the formatting context the box would have participated in if it were `position: static` (independent of its actual containing block). The static position represents an approximation of the position the box would have had if it were `position: static`.

[The *alignment container* is described](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-align-3/#alignment-container) as:

> The alignment container is the rectangle that the alignment subject is aligned within. This is defined by the layout mode, but is usually the alignment subject’s containing block, and assumes the writing mode of the box establishing the containing block.

...so in your case, the *alignment container* of the inner `<div>` is the outer `<div>` because that is the inner `<div>'s` *containing block* because it has `display: block;` by default.